# AlaSQL: Getting where opperands

Tags: alasql

I have a specific request that I'm rather sure it's not trivial, but thought of asking just in case. If I have any query with `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE a = b AND a->fn(b->c) > 0
```

I would like to know all the operands that take part in `WHERE`, in this case `['a', 'b', 'a->fn(b->c)', 0]`.

The reason is that I would want to keep track of those values and if any changes then I would just re-evaluate the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `alasql.parse()` function to produce Abstract Syntax Tree from SQL statement. To print part of the tree from `WHERE` clause of `SELECT` statement please use:

```
var ast = alasql.parse('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE a = b AND a->fn(b->c) > 0');
console.log(ast.statements[0].where);
```

Then you will see the tree structure.

```
{"expression":
   {"left":
       {"left": {"columnid":"a"},"op":"=", "right":{"columnid":"b"}},
     "op":"AND",
     "right":{"left":
                  {"left":{"columnid":"a"},
                   "op":"->",
                   "right":
                        {"funcid":"fn","args":[
                          {"left":{"columnid":"b"},
                           "op":"->",
                           "right":"c"}
                         ]}},
              "op":">",
              "right":{"value":0}}}}
```

You can walk along this tree to collect all arguments. Each node is an object of yy.xxx types, so you can test it:

```
if(node instanceof yy.Column) // then process as the column
```

Is this answer for your question?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need.